# In Huxley's Island, what is a "bass thurible?"

Tags: aldous-huxley, misprint, island

> And now incense was burned in a bass thurible. The old priest held up 
>   his two hands for silence, and through a long pregnant time of the most 
>   perfect stillness the thread of gray incense smoke rose straight and 
>   unwavering before the god, ...
>
> -- *Island* Ch. 10, Pg. 200

A thurible is a metal censer, so brass would make more sense than bass. Is this a typo that was never caught?

Comment: Link to full text https://archive.org/stream/AmusingOurselvesToDeathByNeil203/IslandByAldousHuxley-281__djvu.txt

Comment: It is almost certainly a misprint, since brass, when nicely polished, looks like gold.

Answer (score 7):

The (1976) second reprint on [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.149670/page/n163/mode/2up/search/thurible) refers to it as a ***brass*** thurible. Given that the word brass is notched, it's possible that your version was OCR'd from the archive version.

[image]